# React: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. Sharing state between 2 components and updating it withing each other's component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component-unmount, react-usecallback

I am a newbie in react and developing applications using react js (front) and express (API backend). Let say I have an organization table fetched over through API. The state ***network*** storing the fetched response is shared by both components **<EnhancedTable/>** and **<FullScreenDialog/>** rendered by react router

```
export default function OrganizationTables({nav, setNav}) {
  const {networkName} = useParams();
  const [network, setNetwork] = React.useState(false);
  const networkExists = React.useCallback(async () => {
  let res = await getNetworkExists(networkName);
    if(res.data.network===undefined)
    setNetwork(res.data);
  }, [networkName]);
  React.useEffect(() => {
      networkExists();
  }, [networkExists, key]); 

  return(
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={<EnhancedTable nav={nav} setNav={setNav} network={network} networkName={networkName}/>}/>
      <Route path='/new' element={<FullScreenDialog network={network} setNetwork={setNetwork} />}/>
    </Routes>
)}
```

The <FullScreenDialog> box is used to create a new organization and when successful it redirects (using react router's **useNavigate()** function) it to the <EnhancedTable/>. When doing that I want to update the network state again to catch the newly created organization. So on handleSubmit function I do setNetwork(false) just to change network state. But this error pops up and things don't go as planned.

```
export default function FullScreenDialog({setNetwork}) {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
....
...
 const handleClose = () => navigate(`/superuser/networks/${networkName}/`);
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setLoading(true);
    const data = new FormData(event.currentTarget);
    createOrganization(
      ...
      // CODE
      ...
      .then(() => {setNetwork(false); handleClose()})
      .catch((e)=> e.response.data.DETAILS? setFormResponseAlert(e.response.data.DETAILS): setFormResponseAlert(`Failed to connect to the server. Check your internet connection`))
    .finally(()=>{
      setTimeout(() => {
        setLoading(false);
        setOpen(true);
      }, 500);
    });
  };
...
}
```

Can someone help me with this?
I tried to put a key in Enhanced Component, well it gave me the same error

Comment: setNetwork on first page is holding data and in 2nd page is boolean? is that expected??

Comment: @AyushiKeshri The state network is initialized as false to denote that the useCallback() hasn't run yet. To trigger the useEffect() again which sets the network and calls useCallback(), I am trying to set network to false again in <Enchanced/> component in handleSubmit().

Comment: i dont think this will call your callback function on unmounted component again. what are your requirements can you state pls?

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I actually solved it. 
For anyone looking for an answer ==> The problem was in the handle submit function. Whenever the response is fetched from the server, JS returns it either as a success or an error ( then() and catch() ). In then() block I am directly calling handleClose() which then calls navigate() from react-router library. Ultimately unmounting the component.  The thing is later finally() block executes too which is setting the useState of an unmounted component. Had to cut that down and the problem was solved.